# Add INCLUDE term to primary key index in Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, constraint

I work with Postgres 11 and would like to change the index that backs the primary key of a large table (~750 million rows). The primary key is the `bigint` column `id` and I would like to include an extra column using the `INCLUDE` term. This needs to happen without a table rewrite (i.e. no new/changed columns).

Dropping the current `PRIMARY KEY` constraint isn't convenient, because a lot of other tables reference the target table. I suppose it would be possible to drop the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints on all those tables, then drop the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, recreate using a new index and then recreate the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way, currently. You might automate dropping and recreating FK constraints for convenience. Is concurrent read or write access of concern? Is (temporary) storage size of concern?

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping something would get me around the FK recreation. Automating this might make this easier, yes, that's a good point. Storage should be fine for the additional index and creating the new index concurrently, will probably make the IO okay.

Answer (score 6):

Without messing with the catalogs (which is not commendable), the only option I can think of would require you to do without foreign keys for a while:

You can define a second `UNIQUE` index on the table that contains the appropriate `INCLUDE` clause.

If you use the `CONCURRENTLY` clause of `CREATE INDEX`, that shouldn't be disruptive.

Then you can delete the original primary key constraint and all dependent foreign keys using `DROP INDEX ... CASCADE`.

Then use `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ... USING INDEX` to turn the unique index into a primary key constraint.

Now you can re-create the foreign key constraints.

Comment: True, I could define the new index before I delete the original one, which is probably a good idea in terms of data integrity. Unfortunately it doesn't get me around recreating all foreign key. Using `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` is certainly a good point, too.

Comment: I have revised my answer so that it actually works. You'd have to do without foreign keys for a while.